# Scala Gatling keep inserting user until end of feed file is reached

Tags: scala, gatling

I'm trying to inject users to a scenario in such a way that it will keep inserting user until every single entry of the feed file is used since the feed file contains log in information. I would like all the users in the feed file to log in. Right now all I could think of is two possible approaches.

1. Here I insert the number of rows in the feedfile at once.

   ```
   scenario("Verified_Login")
     .exec(LoginScenario.scn)
     .inject(atOnceUsers(number_of_entries_in_feedfile))
   ```
2. Here I insert a very high time duration, for example, 100 seconds and then make the feedfile circular.

   ```
   scenario("Verified_Login")
     .exec(LoginScenario.scn)
     .inject(atOnceUsers(1),constantUsersPerSec(1) during(100 seconds)
   ```

The problem with the first approach is I have to find the number of entries in the feed file which can be tedious as there could be thousands there. The problem with the second is that entries could and probably will be repeated. So is there a way to keep injecting users till feed file runs out of entries?

Answer (score 2):

According to [this](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/gatling/9ssx0nZy9TA) source, from last year, Stéphane Landelle - who is the leading [contributor](https://github.com/gatling/gatling/graphs/contributors) of gatling, says that you must provide enough data for a simulation to complete using this method.

The post I linked from Stéphane does suggest to simply read the length of the file and use that to drive the amount of users, as you have already mentioned in your question.

I suggest you read the post as it will give you an alternate method to achieving what you want. Seems to be as close as you will ever get unless things have changed.

Here is their code.

```
  val systemsIdentifier = jdbcFeeder(databaseUrl, databaseUser, databasePassword, sql_systemsIdentifier)

  val count = new AtomicInteger(systemsIdentifier.records.size).asLongAs(_ => count.getAndIncrement < systemsIdentifier.records.size)

  val comScn = scenario("My scenario")
   .repeat(systemsIdentifier.records.size / count) {
     feed(systemsIdentifier)
     .exec(performActionsChain)
   }

  setUp(comScn.inject(rampUsers(count) over (60 seconds))).protocols(httpConf)
```